# Need to Replace tags field in json with new value

Tags: json, sed, jq

I am trying to write a batch script to change the value of "tags" key for below 2 jsons named example1.json and example2.json.

input example1.json

```
{
  "info": {
    "title": "My example swagger 1",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/v1/resource1": {
        "get": {
            "description": "This is the example1",
            "tags": [
                "example1"
            ],
            "consumes": [
                "*/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "/v1/resource2": {
        "get": {
            "tags": [
                "example1"
            ],
            "consumes": [
                "*/*"
            ]
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Input example2.json

```
{
 "info": {
    "title": "My example swagger 2",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/v1/resource3": {
        "get": {
            "description": "This is the example2",
            "tags": [
                "example2"
            ],
            "consumes": [
                "*/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "/v1/resource4": {
        "get": {
            "tags": [
                "example2"
            ],
            "consumes": [
                "*/*"
            ]
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Expected Output is two jsons with same name but the tags value is now changed.

Example1.json :

input tags value - example1 (which is json file name)

output tags value - tags1   (as per requirement)

Example2.json

input tags value - example2 (which is json file name)

output tags value - tags2  (as per requirement)

Output Example1.json

```
{
  "info": {
    "title": "My example swagger 1",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/v1/resource1": {
        "get": {
            "description": "This is the example1",
            "tags": [
                "tag1"
            ],
            "consumes": [
                "*/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "/v1/resource2": {
        "get": {
            "tags": [
                "tag1"
            ],
            "consumes": [
                "*/*"
            ]
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Ouput Example2.json

```
{
  "info": {
    "title": "My example swagger 2",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/v1/resource3": {
        "get": {
            "description": "This is the example2",
            "tags": [
                "tag2"
            ],
            "consumes": [
                "*/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "/v1/resource4": {
        "get": {
            "tags": [
                "tag2"
            ],
            "consumes": [
                "*/*"
            ]
       }
    }
  }
}
```

I wrote below commands in batch script but it is not working

```
sed -i "s/$/ #removenewlines#/" %1 
sed -i ":a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g" %1
sed -i "s/\"tags\":\(.*\) \"%oldtagvalue%\"/\"tags\":\1 \"%newtagvalue%\"/g" %1
sed -i "s/ #removenewlines#/\n/g" %1
```

As sed don't work for multiple lines, I changed the newline to #removenewlines# and moving everything to single line(line 1 and 2) . In line 3, I am trying to find key tags using wildcard `\(.*\)` and variable `%oldtagvalue%`and then substituting it with `%newtagvalue%` . In line 4, I am formatting the json back.
The above code runs in loop, so for first loop values of variables will be

```
$ echo %1 
$ example1.json
$ echo %oldtagvalue%
$ example1
$ echo %newtagvalue%
$ tag1
```

For the second loop values will be

```
$ echo %1 
$ example2.json
$ echo %oldtagvalue%
$ example2
$ echo %newtagvalue%
$ tag2
```

But it is not working. Please advice. I also tried to achieve it using jq command but it didn't worked as well.

Comment: Your "JSON" is not valid. It's impossible for us to figure out the actual intended structure of that blob of text. Please fix it.

Comment: @ApG - The question is very unclear.  Please specify how each of the tags values (within a file) is to be changed, and also give an example of the expected output.

Comment: @JeffMercado ..I have corrected the json . Please advice

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly, you want to replace tags that have the file's name and replace it with a tag of your choosing.  Here's one way you could do it:

```
$ jq --arg newtag 'tag1' '(input_filename | sub("\\.json$"; "")) as $oldtag
    | .paths[][].tags |= map(if . == $oldtag then $newtag else . end)' example1.json
```

If you wanted to replace arbitrary tags and not just the one that matches the file name, just add another parameter:

```
$ jq --arg oldtag 'example1' --arg newtag 'tag1' \
    '.paths[][].tags |= map(if . == $oldtag then $newtag else . end)' example1.json
```

If you wanted to be able to replace multiple different tags, you can create an object mapping old tags to new tags and build off that.

```
$ jq --argjson tagmap '{"example1":"tag1","example2":"tag2"}' \
    '.paths[][].tags |= map($tagmap[.] // .)' example1.json
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
$ jq --arg tag "tag1" '
  .paths |= with_entries(.value.get.tags[] = $tag)' Example1.json
```

Or on a slightly different tack, you could use this filter:

```
# Apply f to composite entities recursively, and to atoms
def walk(f):
  . as $in
  | if type == "object" then
      reduce keys[] as $key
        ( {}; . + { ($key):  ($in[$key] | walk(f)) } ) | f
  elif type == "array" then map( walk(f) ) | f
  else f
  end;
walk(if type=="object" and has("tags") then .tags[] |= $tag else . end)
```

In both cases, the output would be as shown below.  You could of course also change "exampleN" to "tagN" programmatically within the jq program (e.g. using `sub/2`), if that's what you want.  The important point is that jq alone can do the job.

```
{
  "info": {
    "title": "My example swagger 1",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/v1/resource1": {
      "get": {
        "description": "This is the example1",
        "tags": [
          "tag1"
        ],
        "consumes": [
          "*/*"
        ]
      }
    },
    "/v1/resource2": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "tag1"
        ],
        "consumes": [
          "*/*"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```